# Android Class extends View and Placement on MainActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I am having trouble in Placing a View into main activity, what I did is,

I have a file Lines.java and in this file, we have all the functionality of drawing a circle, this circle class extends view
 as shown below

```
public class Lines extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();

public Views(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
      canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 20, paint);
      System.out.println("called");
}}
```

now in MainActivity I am creating a object of this circle class and placing it into setcontentview(obj);

below is the code snippet for that

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Linesobj=new Lines(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(obj);
}
```

}

when I do this it takes whole screen place, I don't want that, I want to place it into main activity I tried through xml using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523734/android-custom-view-from-xml-layout) link, I am enclosing a picture of MainActivity, I want to place that view right in the middle of activity 
**Red rectangle shows where I want to place Lines class(i.e View)**

Your help is appreciated ! !

[image: Red rectangle shows where I want to place Lines class(View)]

XML FILE

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.compoundview.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Line" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Free" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <com.example.compoundview.Views
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML file for you activity? It will be relevant here.

Comment: Could you show us the full contents of MainActivity, please? Obviously with any business-type info removed.

Comment: Shotgun Ninja, I just started there is nothing , just declared a object of Lines and thats all

Comment: McAdam331, I have posted a XML file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it takes over the entire view is because that is what you are doing when you call `setContentView`. From the docs:

> Set the activity content to an explicit view. This view is placed directly into the activity's view hierarchy.

Therefore, whatever you have in your XML (be it a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, whatever) will be replaced by your custom View. To fix this, you need to add the view programatically to the existing layout. For example, if you have a LinearLayout, you can add your circle like this:

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_linear_layout);
mLinearLayout.addView(obj);
```

Here are the docs for [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)). For a RelativeLayout, it will look a little different. I'd reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418929/add-view-programmatically-to-relativelayout).

With your edit, I see that you have both a RelativeLayout and a LinearLayout. So, which route you use programatically will depend on where you want your object to be placed in the view hierarchy, which is completely up to you.

Comment: I am getting java.lang.NullpointerException on graphics.Path.reset(); if I use mLinearLayout.addView(obj);

but if I used setcontentview(obj) it works fine? what's the catch?